# Cursorfetch error because of wrong variable type

Tags: sql, sql-server

i try to do a benchmark for SQL Statments for SQLServer.

I found a good benchmark loop online: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/Benchmarks/SQLServer/Benchmarking%20SQL%20Server%20(absolute).sql

```
DECLARE @ts DATETIME;
DECLARE @repeat INT = 10000;
DECLARE @r INT;
DECLARE @i INT;
DECLARE @dummy VARCHAR;

DECLARE @s1 CURSOR;
DECLARE @s2 CURSOR;

SET @r = 0;
WHILE @r < 5
BEGIN
  SET @r = @r + 1

  SET @s1 = CURSOR FOR
  -- Paste statement 1 here
  SELECT 1 x;

  SET @s2 = CURSOR FOR
  -- Paste statement 2 here
  WITH t(v) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT v + 1 FROM t WHERE v < 10
  )
  SELECT * FROM t

  SET @ts = current_timestamp;
  SET @i = 0;
  WHILE @i < @repeat
  BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1

    OPEN @s1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @s1 INTO @dummy;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM @s1 INTO @dummy;
    END;

    CLOSE @s1;
  END;

  DEALLOCATE @s1;
  PRINT 'Run ' + CAST(@r AS VARCHAR) + ', Statement 1: ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, @ts, current_timestamp) AS VARCHAR) + 'ms';

  SET @ts = current_timestamp;
  SET @i = 0;
  WHILE @i < @repeat
  BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1

    OPEN @s2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @s2 INTO @dummy;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM @s2 INTO @dummy;
    END;

    CLOSE @s2;
  END;

  DEALLOCATE @s2;
  PRINT 'Run ' + CAST(@r AS VARCHAR) + ', Statement 2: ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, @ts, current_timestamp) AS VARCHAR) + 'ms';
END;

PRINT '';
PRINT 'Copyright Data Geekery GmbH';
PRINT 'https://www.jooq.org/benchmark';
```

This works great for when the statments i test only have one column they return. For example:

```
Select ID from Items Where ID=2;
```

But as soon as i try to select multiple rows like

```
Select * from Items Where ID=2;
```

i get the error:

> Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 135 Cursorfetch: The number of
>   variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected
>   columns.

So the column this concerns is

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @s1 INTO @dummy;
```

So as far as i understand the issue is that i try to fit to much columsn into the dummy variable. But how do i fix it? Im not so long working with SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward - youre pulling more data than you have variables for. If you need to pull more columns then you need to have a variable for each.

Comment: So for 3 columns i need to have dumm1 dumm2 and dummy 3? Or is there a way where i just declare one array with 3 items? Because i want to test a query with 63 columsn and thats kinda tedious.

Comment: Well you could query the sys.Columns table and get the column names that way. It would be some extra code but would allow you to do this in a more "clean" fashion. However, Im confused as to what your end point is to be. Is a cursor the best way to do this? or is the requirement to use a cursor. knowing the data and the end result might allow someone to give you better advice.

Comment: For me the endpoint ist to benchmark querys. I just found the code and im not advanced enough in sql to say what would be the best way to modify it. 

I also need the benchmark to run with many different querys. So it cant be adjusted just for the single query i showed here as an example. 

I think in the end the esiest way for me is to declare 63 dummy variables. I there would be a solution where i just decalre an array (think for sql its a table) and can then just write it all inside.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by benchmark queries. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Run a query a thousand times to so how long on average it takes. I then optimze the querry and run it again to see if my optimazation made it faster.

Comment: You know all of this information is already available right? There are tons of views/tables and procs/functions all dedicate to diagnostic type logging. Here's just one example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also, you can also look at client statistics and the execution plan - all providing valuable information. You could even use third party tools dedicated to this as well.

Comment: No i didnt knew that. Thanks. But it also doesnt help me. The Database is used in two ways: One way is the requests from scripts people run manually. I can change stuff here and want to improve it. 

The other way is by a third party programm. I cant change stuff there. The command you showed me is showing me all the queries from the programm i supposed. 

Basically i need som way to manually run benchmarks.

Comment: You know that was meant as an example, right? Did you bother to google any of the things I said? Like "Client Statistics" or "Execution Plan"? Youre literally in front of a computer :P Query optimization is a very broad topic and requires a bigger thinking perspective sometimes. It ranges from Index Analysis, SQL Syntax, Query Structure, Waits, Blocks/Locks, Resource Considerations, Execution Plan analysis and what I might consider common sense. Focusing purely on timing might be shot sighted at best and ignoring all the fun parts.

Comment: Your approach to testing performance is flawed critically. You have introduced nested cursors.

Comment: Well geez @SeanLange I was trying to be nice about it LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a useful or simple way to test queries.

It’s a lot of code so it’s not particularly easy, and uses a cursor to process the results so it includes the cost of processing the results on the server with a cursor, which is not present normally.

Normally you just run the query in SSMS and look at the Actual Execution Plan and perhaps the time and IO statistics, and perhaps the client statistics.  The query results should be returned to the client, because that's what happens in production, and you should consider the time needed to transmit results over the network when benchmarking.

If you need to run a query without returning data to the client, you can use a pattern like

```
go
set statistics io on
set statistics time on
go
drop table if exists #foo;

with q as
(
  select ...
  from ...
)
select *
into #foo
from q
go 5
set statistics io off
set statistics time off
go
```

Comment: The point of such benchmarks is to run a query 100s or 1000s of times to get averages, standard deviations, etc. in order to reduce side effects of an otherwise busy server, or startup penalties, caching, etc.

Comment: Yes @LukasEder this is exactly my goal what i try to reach. And it works good. Only problem is when i want to select multiple columns as output.

Comment: Trying to learn something here. How is this approach significantly better than the OP's? I mean, the OP could add the `set statistics` calls to the script just the same... This approach here seems to include the overhead of managing the temporary table, and the associated I/O... Your answer isn't very specific with respect to *"That is not a useful or simple way to test queries."*

Comment: See update above.  And the temp table is only there if you don’t want to return the results to the client.  Normally you would return the results to the client because that’s what a real query does.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: I think you're missing the point of the benchmark. If transmission time was relevant, of course, the same benchmark could be written from a client, e.g. written in C# or Java, or whatever. But it is also interesting to benchmark execution time from within a database only. I mean, the "client" could as well be implemented in T-SQL, in case of which this approach would be perfectly valid. I'd love to learn what the big flaw really is here.

Comment: The flaw is the cursor, and the need to change the code significantly to change the query being tested.